# CSS transition does not work when changing the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to modify some element styles via CSS and I expect certain transitions, but I cannot get them to work if I move them to a different parent element (which is essential in my application).

Here is a minimal example:

```js
    var a = $('#a'), b = $('#b'), box = $('.box'), current = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      if(++current % 2 == 0) {
        box.appendTo(b).addClass('in-b').removeClass('in-a');
      } else {
       box.appendTo(a).addClass('in-a').removeClass('in-b');
      }
    }, 3000);
```

```css
    #a, #b {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .box {
      background-color: #50A000;
      transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .box.box.in-a {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .box.box.in-b {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="a">
      <div class="box in-a">
      Hello world!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b"></div>
```

How can I solve this issue? I need to move elements to a different parent, change some styles and still ensure that the transitions work properly.

Comment: IIRC, you'd need to remove and re-add the elements to the DOM for this to work, rather than just move them.

Comment: @RyanGee Using `.remove().appendTo()` does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are toggling the classes too quickly, the DOM needs to update to the new structure before it will do a new transition.

You can use `setTimeout` call with a very short delay like 10 to accomplish this. And since you are using just two classes and switching them between each interval you can just use `toggleClass("in-a in-b")` instead of doing separate add/removeClass calls.

```
setTimeout(()=>box.toggleClass("in-a in-b"),10);
```

Demo

```js
var a = $('#a'),
  b = $('#b'),
  box = $('.box'),
  current = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (++current % 2 == 0) {
    box.appendTo(b);
  } else {
    box.appendTo(a);
  }
  setTimeout(() => box.toggleClass("in-a in-b"), 10);
}, 3000);
```

```css
#a,
#b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box {
  background-color: #50A000;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.box.box.in-a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.box.box.in-b {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">
  <div class="box in-a">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```